# How to update matrix based on multiple maximum value per row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix, row

I am a newbie to Python.  I have an NxN matrix and I want to know the maximum value per each row. Next, I want to nullify(update as zero) all other values except this maximum value. If the row contains multiple maximum values, all those maximum values should be preserved.

Using DataFrame, I tried to get the maximum of each row.Then I tried to get indices of these max values. Code is given below.

```
 matrix = [(22, 16, 23),
          (12, 6, 43),
          (24, 67, 11),
          (87, 9,11),
          (66, 36,66)
          ]
  dfObj = pd.DataFrame(matrix, index=list('abcde'), columns=list('xyz'))
  maxValuesObj = dfObj.max(axis=1)
  maxValueIndexObj = dfObj.idxmax(axis=1)
```

The above code doesn't consider multiple maximum values. Only the first occurrence is returned.
Also,I am stuck with how to update the matrix accordingly. My expected output is:

```
matrix = [(0, 0, 23),
              (0, 0, 43),
              (0, 67, 0),
              (87, 0,0),
              (66, 0,66)
              ]
```

Can you please help me to sort out this?

Comment: `[tuple([i if i == max(elem) else 0 for i in elem]) for elem in matrix]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show how to do it with a Python built-ins instead of Pandas, since you're new to Python and should know how to do it outside of Pandas (and the Pandas syntax isn't as clean).

```
 matrix = [(22, 16, 23),
          (12, 6, 43),
          (24, 67, 11),
          (87, 9,11),
          (66, 36,66)
          ]
new_matrix = []
for row in matrix:
    row_max = max(row)
    new_row = tuple(element if element == row_max else 0 for element in row)
    new_matrix.append(new_row)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [`df.where()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
dfObj.where(dfObj.eq(dfObj.max(1),axis=0),0)
```

---

```
    x   y   z
a   0   0  23
b   0   0  43
c   0  67   0
d  87   0   0
e  66   0  66
```

For an ND array instead of a dataframe , call [`.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) after the above code:

```
dfObj.where(dfObj.eq(dfObj.max(1),axis=0),0).values
```

Or better is [`to_numpy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html):

```
dfObj.where(dfObj.eq(dfObj.max(1),axis=0),0).to_numpy()
```

Or [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
np.where(dfObj.eq(dfObj.max(1),axis=0),dfObj,0)
```

---

```
array([[ 0,  0, 23],
       [ 0,  0, 43],
       [ 0, 67,  0],
       [87,  0,  0],
       [66,  0, 66]], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a short for loop pretty easily:

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([(22, 16, 23), (12, 6, 43), (24, 67, 11), (87, 9,11), (66, 36,66)])

for i in range(0, len(matrix)):
    matrix[i] = [x if x == max(matrix[i]) else 0 for x in matrix[i]]

print(matrix)
```

output:

```
[[ 0  0 23]
 [ 0  0 43]
 [ 0 67  0]
 [87  0  0]
 [66  0 66]]
```

I would also use numpy for matrices not pandas.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the most performant solution, but you can write a function for the row operation then apply it to each row:

```
def max_row(row):
    row.loc[row != row.max()] = 0
    return row

dfObj.apply(max_row, axis=1)

Out[17]: 
    x   y   z
a   0   0   23
b   0   0  43
c   0  67   0
d  87   0   0
e  66   0  66
```